# iOS Siri Shortcuts: Can I hide action buttons on Siri?

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I'm trying to create custom Siri shortcut with Intents UI.
What I want to know is how I make custom intent which has no button on Siri interface.

Image is like Kayak's Siri Interface.
https://www.apple.com/newsroom/images/product/os/ios/standard/ios12_iphonexs-siritravelplans-09172018_inline.jpg.large_2x.jpg

When I create custom intent from intentdefinition file, I have to choose certain category from limited categories list (Do, Order, Start etc). Then I call my custom intent, Siri shows action buttons ("Do", "Order", "Cancel") in the interface bottom area. But I want not to display these action buttons. Can I have a way? I've read official documents, unfortunately I did't found it.

Comment: OK, I found it. Just simple.

Just uncheck Confirmation's "User confirmation required" on intentdefinition file.

Comment: Post an answer! I find there is still a UI glitch when I do it this way (the action UI appears briefly and then disappears). Do you see that as well?